# Searching within a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, varchar, varbinary

I'm trying to get my query to use a where clause to find information coming back from a query that is casting a particular column as varbinary and varchar. I have to cast because the original data is in hex.

My query:

```
SELECT ScriptID, RowOrder, cast(cast(ScriptData as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)) AS Converted_SD
FROM Script_Data
```

A typical return would be something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ScriptID | RowOrder | Converted_SD                                                       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 5006     | 1        | CVisScript {331 1 76 "\"1007\"" "Call.PeripheralVariable10" 284 "" |
| 5007     | 1        | CVisScript {332 1 76 "\"2007\"" "Call.PeripheralVariable10" 285 "" |
| 5009     | 1        | CVisScript {333 1 76 "\"1037\"" "Call.PeripheralVariable10" 286 "" |
| 5014     | 1        | CVisScript {334 1 76 "\"1407\"" "Call.PeripheralVariable10" 287 "" |
| 5015     | 1        | CVisScript {335 1 76 "\"1068\"" "Call.PeripheralVariable10" 288 "" |
| 5016     | 1        | CVisScript {336 1 76 "\"6578\"" "Call.PeripheralVariable10" 289 "" |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'd like to be able to return the ScriptID, RowOrder, but only return Call.PeripheralVariable10 and and the four digits that prepend it - nothing else in the Converted_SD column. I've tried so many subqueries, but I just can't seem to put one together that will work. So I envision it to look something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| ScriptID | RowOrder | Converted_SD                   |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 5006     | 1        | 1007 Call.PeripheralVariable10 |
| 5007     | 1        | 2007 Call.PeripheralVariable10 |
| 5009     | 1        | 1037 Call.PeripheralVariable10 |
| 5014     | 1        | 1407 Call.PeripheralVariable10 |
| 5015     | 1        | 1068 Call.PeripheralVariable10 |
| 5016     | 1        | 6578 Call.PeripheralVariable10 |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Thank You

Comment: Apologizes... I'm using MS SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL server 2016 you can make use of string_split function.

You can see on its usage here (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4884/sql-server-2016-stringsplit-function/)

If you know the format will always be Call with Double quotes, you can use this function in Double Quotes or make the same delimiter if you have multiple formats with replace.

```
with cte as  (
select 5006 as ScriptID,  1 RowOrder, 'CVisScript {331 1 76 "\"1007\"" "Call.PeripheralVariable10" 284 ""' as Con_SD union all 
select 5007 as ScriptID,  1 RowOrder, 'CVisScript {332 1 76 "\"2007\"" "Call.PeripheralVariable10" 285 ""' as Con_SD union all 
select 5009 as ScriptID,  1 RowOrder, 'CVisScript {333 1 76 "\"1037\"" "Call.PeripheralVariable10" 286 ""' as Con_SD union all 
select 5014 as ScriptID,  1 RowOrder, 'CVisScript {334 1 76 "\"1407\"" "Call.PeripheralVariable10" 287 ""' as Con_SD union all 
select 5015 as ScriptID,  1 RowOrder, 'CVisScript {335 1 76 "\"1068\"" "Call.PeripheralVariable10" 288 ""' as Con_SD union all 
select 5016 as ScriptID,  1 RowOrder, 'CVisScript {336 1 76 "\"6578\"" "Call.PeripheralVariable10" 289   ' as Con_SD )


select c.ScriptID, c.RowOrder, tbl.n   from cte c  
cross apply  (select * from  string_split (con_SD, '"'))   tbl(n)
where tbl.n like '%call%';
```

Output:

[image]